# checkSystemClipboardAccess alternative for JDK11

Tags: java, clipboard, java-11

JDK11 has removed `checkSystemClipboardAccess` from `SecurityManager`. What's the suggested alternative idiom in Clipboard handling?

I wanted to check Clipboard availability like this:

```
public static boolean hasClipboard() {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm == null) return true;
    try {
        sm.checkSystemClipboardAccess();
        return true;
    } catch (SecurityException x) {
        /* */
    }
    return false;
}
```

But its impossible to compile it in JDK11.

**Edit 01.02.2020:**
Based on suggestions I am now using:

```
public static boolean hasClipboard() {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm == null) return true;
    try {
        sm.checkPermission(new AWTPermission("accessClipboard"));
        return true;
    } catch (SecurityException x) {
        /* */
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The [Javadoc for `checkSystemClipboardAccess()` in JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkSystemClipboardAccess--) states _"**The dependency on AWTPermission creates an impediment to future modularization** of the Java platform"_ so using `java.awt.AWTPermission` as a workaround might not be a long term solution. The Javadoc also states _"this method will be changed in a future release to check the permission `java.security.AllPermission`"_ (which doesn't make sense to me), but don't see any clarification on that from any other source.

Comment: @skomisa I think manually using `AWTPermission` _is_ the long term solution (and the documentation quoted in the answers would seem to agree). The quote you mention is related to the modularization of _the JDK itself_. If a class in the `java.base` module required a class in the `java.desktop` module that would be a problem since the former module is supposed to be the, well, _base_ module. If a user application depends on `java.desktop` then that's okay because presumably it's using AWT or Swing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Google] search for the terms *java checkSystemClipboardAccess removed* provided a link to Oracle's *javadoc* for class `SecurityManager` (JDK 10), and the documentation for method [checkSystemClipboardAccess()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkSystemClipboardAccess()) contains the following:

> Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.
>   This method was originally used to check if the calling thread could access the system clipboard. The method has been obsoleted and code should instead use checkPermission(java.security.Permission) to check AWTPermission("accessClipboard"). This method is subject to removal in a future version of Java SE.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix is to simply replace your call to `sm.checkSystemClipboardAccess();` with a call to `sm.checkPermission(new java.awt.AWTPermission("accessClipboard"));`.

See Oracle's JDK 8 technote [Permissions in the Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) which explicitly addresses the deprecation of `checkSystemClipboardAccess()`:

> Method
>
> public void checkSystemClipboardAccess(); Note: **This method is
>   deprecated; use instead public void checkPermission(Permission perm);**
>
> Permission
>
> java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";